# Move/rotate all objects contained in a collection around the space

Tags: objects, parent, collections, groups, viewlayers

I have modelled a car and I have arranged all differents objects parts in nested collections under a main one called "Model". Now I need to move all the car in the space I know that I can use parent object for link all objects to a main one but in this way it take a lot of time because I have hundreds of objects, is there a way to move it just by selecting the main "model" collection? If no what you suggest me to do? Maybe I can substitute the nested collections with empties object and parent all to it?

Comment: if you select one of the collection's objects and press shift G you can select all the collection's objects, but in my opinion it's better to create an empty and parent all the car's objects to this empty, or parent them all to the main object, for example the main body part

Comment: I hope one day we'll can use collections like group objects

Comment: I know that it has been suggested, I don't know if it will be implemented though

Comment: Collections can be used like group objects (if talking about groups in 2.79-). Shift+A > Collection instance > choose name > add to scene. Then move it as you wish. You can change its origin with Search menu > Set origin

Comment: Nice is what I was looking for! But I've tried and it seems make a duplicate of the collection, how can I rotate the instance collection and keep the main one not rotated and toggle the visibility for render? Let's assume I want a instance of the car rotated 180° to make some renders of the car's tail, but I want the main collection not rotated for future rendering of the front car (without change rotation or position of the camera)?

Comment: SOLVED Like Mr Zak suggest me I've used Collection Instance, rotated 180° this instance unchecked the visibility oh the main collection and that's all, thanks Mr Zak!